# Trying to catch SIGSEGV signal in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

My aim is to change the permission on a virtual memory zone, from `read-only` to `read-write`. This should happen only after a SIGSEGV signal has happened.

I have registered a handler for the SIGSEGV signal, and also found a way of changing the permission to `read-write`.

The current issue that I am facing is that the handler doesn't get executed.

Any ideas?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sigint_handler(int signo, siginfo_t *var, void *unused){
        mprotect(var->si_addr, 4, PROT_WRITE);
}

const char str[4] = "abc";

int main(){
        struct sigaction act;

        act.sa_sigaction = sigint_handler;

        sigfillset(&act.sa_mask);

        sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL);

        printf("%s\n", str);
        //printf("-->%d\n",str[-1000]);

        memcpy(str, "123", strlen("123"));

        printf("%s\n", str);

        return (0);
}```
````

Comment: You can't execute code in virtual memory. Only code loaded within real memory is able to be executed.

Comment: Where the signal is being triggered?

Comment: When I test under strace, the handler does get executed, but `var->si_addr` is `-1` so the `mprotect` fails (you didn't check its return value).

Comment: Check the `sigaction` man page.  You have to set the `SA_SIGINFO` flag if you want to get the `siginfo_t` argument.

Comment: The signal handler _does_ get triggered. You can verify this by running under `gdb` and putting a breakpoint on `sigint_handler`. But, what do you want to do? This is a special case. While the signal handler might set write permission (you want: `PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE` and _not_ just `PROT_WRITE`), you'd have to force the program to restart the [deliberately] offending instruction, which is problematic--An app isn't an OS kernel.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Returning from the signal handler will normally restart the instruction.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Currently I have added the flag `SA_SIGINFO` and further the `PROT_READ` . Currently I want to change the permission of the `const char` expression in order to override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main bugs:

- When calling `sigaction`, you have to set the `SA_SIGINFO` flag in `act.sa_flags` in order to have the second argument passed to your signal handler.  As it stands that field is just uninitialized.
- `mprotect` requires that its `addr` argument be page aligned.  (This will also require you to recompute the `len` argument accordingly to ensure the desired region is covered.)  As a quick-and-dirty example, assuming the page size is 4096, you can mask off the corresponding low bits by ANDing with the bitwise complement of 4095.

```c
    uintptr_t orig = (uintptr_t)var->si_addr;
    uintptr_t aligned = orig & ~4095UL;
    mprotect((void *)aligned, orig + 4 - aligned, PROT_WRITE) < 0);
```

Both requirements are explained in the corresponding man pages.  Checking for error returns from your system calls would also have helped you narrow down the problem (you'd have seen that your signal handler *does* execute but the `mprotect` call fails because of invalid arguments).

With these fixed, the program works as intended for me under Linux.

Comment: Would you please share the code as well? I have added the flag, but I'm having issues understanding the addr alignment .

Comment: He's got a third bug where he is not setting the sigaction struct to zero. Since it is a local variable it will contain random stack junk unless it is set.

Comment: @ZanLynx: that is the first bug above -- the flags is uninitialized.  When properly initialized, it specifies which other fields contain valid data (unused fields don't need to be zeroed, as they'll be ignored).

Comment: @JohnnyOnPc: Added example of aligning the address.

Comment: @ZanLynx: That is correctly set.  You can't safely use a struct initialization as the order of the fields and the presence or absence of padding (or unions to combine fields) is not specified by POSIX.  Memsetting the whole thing is a waste as you still need to set all the relevant fields afterwards anyways.